# How to set the required version of C++ redistributables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, redistributable

I created a dll based off a sample project that is several years old.
I am building the dll and can register this dll successfully on my computer which has both 2010 and 2015-2019 C++ redistributables installed.
When I try to install this same dll on a computer with only 2015-2019 c++ redistributables installed, registration fails.  After installing the 2010 c++ redistributables on that machine, the dll installed successfully.
I would like to be able to register this dll on a computer with only the 2015-2019 redistributables installed.  I assume this has something to do with the configuration of the project which I'm building in Visual Studio 2019.  I've poked through all the properties but nothing stands out.  Would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction!

Update: The sample I am referring to comes with the Windows sdk and can be found here: C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\Windows-classic-samples\Samples\Win7Samples\winui\shell\appshellintegration\RecipeThumbnailProvider
When I opened it up in Visual Studio 2019 it did some kind of update, but doesn't seem to have affected the redistributable it depends on.

Comment: It's dependant on the `Platform Toolset` used to build the program. See [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @RichardCritten I have read this article but I'm confused because it says, "We only support using a redistributable package that's the same as or newer than your toolset version."  Doesn't this mean that if my dll wants the 2010 redistributables that it should work with the 2015-2019 version since that's newer?  Where can I set my "platform toolset" when building?

Comment: _"...Where can I set my "platform toolset" when building?..."_ Project (not Solution) Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, it's showing "Visual Studio 2019 (v142)" which seems like it's what I want... Any other ideas on why it seems to need the 2010 redistributables installed?

Comment: Do you have any pre-built components if so use Dependency Walker (note it's not been updated in a while and can give confusing output) to check what they need.

Comment: Apparently dependency walker is out of date (and hangs when I try to use it), but I found [this newer project](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies):  It shows I'm missing ext-ms-win-oobe-query-l1-1-0.dll,HvsiFileTrust.dll, & ext-ms-win32-subsystem-query-l1-1-0.dll  BUT, this also shows up when I look on the machine where registration works.  To my knowledge I do not have any pre-built components.  I updated the question with the sample my project is based on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being related to the fact that I'm using JNI and was dependent on jvm.dll.  I was using the jvm.dll from Java 8u202.  This version of the dll is dependent on the 2010 C++ Redistributables.  Starting with Java 8u261 jvm.dll is dependent on the 2017 Redistributables ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes003.html)).

Dependency Walker is outdated, but this newer tool, [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), worked with my dll.